# regular expression (JS) for phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a regular expression to take `+Z (YYY) XXX-XX-XX`, and get `YYYXXXXXXX`? This is for phone number.

Comment: @NullPointer Is that is posted by a 2.3k repo user ?

Comment: Of course i want something nicer, if possible :)

Comment: @Luntegg a nicer solution i have posted check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by

```
var mobile = "+Z (567) 567-567-567";
  var n=mobile.replace("(","");
 n =n.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''); 

alert(n)​
```

### [jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6H8E/)

Comment: I need to cut the first option, and get out of it the second option

Comment: then try   s = mobile.substr(2);

Answer (score 0):

if you have exact the format `+Z (YYY) XXX-XX-XX`:

```
var num = input.replace( '/^\+\S+\s\((\d{3})\)\s(\d{3})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/', '\1\2\3\4' );
```

but a more tolerant variant would be

```
var num = input.replace( '/^(\+\S+|\D/', '' );
```